# Use CSS to change the photos within a dropdown menu

Tags: css, menu, widget

I am using a donation widget from another company which I have made use of on my website. I would like to change the size of the photos in the dropdown menu next to the item on the menu. I want to change it to 50x50 pixels.

Unfortunately, all I have is the widget code itself. I do have a [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILHSo.jpg), that could help to clear up what I'm talking about.

```
$data.WebPhotoId {
    max-width: 50px; 
    max-height: 50px:
}

dropdown-menu databind= {
    max-width:50px;
    max-height:50px;

    body {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
        color: #676767;
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any way I modify my CSS in order to change the menu item pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is set with `<img src="path/to/image">` you can't do it nicely with CSS.

In that case I would suggest using JavaScript or jQuery for this.

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image-class')
for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
  image[i].src="path/to/new/image";
}
```

With CSS you can set `background-image: url('path/to/new/image')` but I don't think it will work in case where image is set with `<img src="path/to/image">`